# UIProgressView and Custom Track and Progress Images (iOS 5 properties)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, uiprogressview

I am experimenting with some new properties in iOS 5 regarding `UIProgressView`. They are:

`@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *progressImage;`
`@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *trackImage;`

These new properties enable the customisation of the "*progress*" and the "*track*" image, so that you can make fancy progress bars without having to roll-your-own.

I however cannot understand how Apple "*stretches*" the progress images, because documentation is a little flakey / OR there is some standard I am not aware of. **Regardless, I am asking if someone can help me understand how to make appropriate progress and tracking images.**

I get results like this when I load my custom images, no matter which sizes I try:

[image: Progress Example]

My measurements are as follows:

- UIProgressView length: 226 units
- trackingImage.png: 10px
- progressImage.png: 7px

Lastly, here are my custom images:

[image: The Progress Image] `progressImage.png`

[image: The Tracking Image] `trackImage.png`

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Here's what's going on:

The images you provide to the `UIProgressView` are basically being shoved in to `UIImageViews`, and the `UIImageView` is stretching the image to fill the space.

If you simply do:

```
[progressView setTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"track.png"]];
```

Then you're going to get weird results, because it's trying to stretch a 10px wide image to fill (for example) a 100px wide image view.  This means (roughly) that every pixel in the image will be repeated 10 times.  So if the pixels in our image were:

```
0123456789
```

Then putting that image straight into a 100px wide image view would stretch it something like this:

```
000000000011111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555...
```

This is what's happening to you.

What you *really* want to have happen is this:

```
01234567812345678123456781234567812345678...123456789
```

In other words, you want the image to have a 1 point left edge that is never stretched, the center to be tiled, and to have a 1 point right edge that is also never stretched.  To do this, [you'll need to make the image resizable](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW50):

```
UIImage *track = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"track"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 1, 0, 1)];
[progressView setTrackImage:track];
```

If you want this to tile appropriately vertically as well, then the edge insets should be `{1, 1, 1, 1}` (assuming you want a 1 point border).

Do the same to the `progressImage`, and you'll end up with something that looks correct:

[image: Correct progressView]

## tl;dr:

Your images need to be resizable.

Comment: According to instruments, this is leaking. I'm using arc. Is anyone else having the same problem? It looks like it could be a UIProgressView bug.

Comment: for some reason, this is only making the track image resizable and not the actual progress image but I'm set up each the same way.

Comment: @Seany242 yep, you'll need to make the `progressImage` a resizable image as well.

Comment: they are the same image, just different colors. I double checked and replaced the setTrackImage: and setProgressImage: variables (load and track, both uiimages set up the same way from the same image) and in both cases, the progress image didn't work but the track image did. ...?

Comment: @Seany242 sounds like great fodder for a new question

Comment: good idea. new question [here:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738361/why-isnt-uiprogressview-progress-bar-resizable)

Comment: And if you want to use a track image with a specific size. Not resizable? How can I set the progress default blue line?

Comment: This is a terrific explanation of pixel scaling. 10/10