# Customized UIProgressView with rounded corner images

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiprogressview

I am having difficulties customizing `UIProgressView` with two images. I have found plenty of helpful questions on the internet, but my problem is a little different.  Maybe in a way that images I am using are rounded on not cornered rectangles; therefore, `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth` method doesn't seem to help in my case.  When I stretch the images, there is some space because of rounded corners of the images, there is one question posted on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980891/uiprogressview-and-custom-track-and-progress-images-ios-5-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to Implement Custom `UiProgressView` and use the following code for your progress view and add your images for filling and background progress view, in my case they are **loaderBar.png** for filling and **timeLineBig.png** for background.

**CustomProgressView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomProgressView : UIProgressView

@end
```

**CustomProgressView.m**

```
#define fillOffsetX 2
#define fillOffsetTopY 2
#define fillOffsetBottomY 2

#import "CustomProgressView.h"

@implementation CustomProgressView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

 CGSize backgroundStretchPoints = {10, 10}, fillStretchPoints = {7, 7};

 // Initialize the stretchable images.
 UIImage *background = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"timelineBig.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:backgroundStretchPoints.width
 topCapHeight:backgroundStretchPoints.height];

 UIImage *fill = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"loaderBar.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:fillStretchPoints.width
 topCapHeight:fillStretchPoints.height];

 // Draw the background in the current rect
 [background drawInRect:rect];

 // Compute the max width in pixels for the fill.  Max width being how
 // wide the fill should be at 100% progress.
 NSInteger maxWidth = rect.size.width - (2 * fillOffsetX);

 // Compute the width for the current progress value, 0.0 - 1.0 corresponding
 // to 0% and 100% respectively.
 NSInteger curWidth = floor([self progress] * maxWidth);

 // Create the rectangle for our fill image accounting for the position offsets,
 // 1 in the X direction and 1, 3 on the top and bottom for the Y.
 CGRect fillRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + fillOffsetX,
 rect.origin.y + fillOffsetTopY,
 curWidth,
 rect.size.height - fillOffsetBottomY);

 // Draw the fill
 [fill drawInRect:fillRect];
 }



@end
```

finally when you want to use the custom progress view then call something like this...

```
self.customProgressView=[[CustomProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xValue, yValue, widthofProgressView, heightofProgressView)];
```

make sure you set your customized values for  **xValue, yValue , widthofProgressView & heightofProgressView** according to your requirements

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will give it a try and get back to you if I face problems

Comment: seem helpful, but still need some fixing in images with respect to height and width I guess, but It looks I will have to arrange it accordingly as you said in your answer, thanks a million

Answer (score 1):

If you having issues streching the image use resize `resizableImageWithCapInsets:`

```
UIImage *image = [baseImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

[You can check out this link](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/ios-5-uiimage-and-resizableimagewithcapinsets.html).