# Rounded corner throughout the whole progress

Tags: ios, uikit, swift3

I have a progress view and I see that if I change its corner radius I get rounded corners when the progress is 1.0 (full), however, I'd like to have rounded corner throughout the whole progress, for example, the image below shows a progress on half way, as you can see only the left end has rounded corners.

[image: Progres (=========]

I already set these properties on the `viewDidLoad`:

```
progressView.clipsToBounds = true
progressView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
progressView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: I think you should search into the sublayer to find de blue one and apply the same treatment

Comment: Check out this similar question in Obj-C: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14775310/1689376

Comment: @bobby True, I did with subviews and didn't work. Now that you said about the sublayers I tried it and and it worked. Place it as an answer and I'll mark it as  the right one.

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad Done :D thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should search into the sublayer to find de blue one and apply the same treatment

Comment: For anyone in the future looking for the right way to access it, this worked for me: `barLayer = progressView.layer.sublayers[1]`. Then adjust the `cornerRadius` and `masksToBounds` properties of that as required.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer

```
// Set the rounded edge for the outer bar
self.layer.cornerRadius = 12
self.clipsToBounds = true

// Set the rounded edge for the inner bar        
self.layer.sublayers![1].cornerRadius = 12
self.subviews[1].clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, @CZ54's answer is correct. Here is the Code.

```
[progressView.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(__kindof UIView * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        obj.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        obj.layer.cornerRadius = progressView.layer.cornerRadius;
    }];
```