# Remove the shadow from a UIProgressView?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiprogressview

I've got a simple UIProgressView with a custom colour, I want to lose the Apple shadow, can this be done?

```
[[UIProgressView appearance] setProgressTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:5/255 green:72/255 blue:255/255 alpha:1.0]];
[[UIProgressView appearance] setTrackTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.000]];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the way that you're thinking. You're going to have to use a couple really basic images.

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980891/uiprogressview-and-custom-track-and-progress-images-ios-5-properties) post for a nice explanation with some good pictures. But basically your going to have to use:

```
[[UIProgressView appearance] setProgressImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ProgressImage"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 1, 0, 1)]];
[[UIProgressView appearance] setTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"TrackImage"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 1, 0, 1)]];
```

With whatever color images you wish to use. If you just want straight colors, then just make some simple little single color blocks or go crazy with some gradients.