# How do i set progress image in UIProgressView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiprogressview

I am trying to set Progress image and Track image for UIProgress view using the designer, preview screen shows me the desired view with track image as the background of the progress bar and Progress image used for progress bar. But when i run my code both the images are not getting used instead progress is displayed using the background color and tint color of the View. Can someone tell me how to override the tint color and background color and use Progress image and Track Image property.

[image]

Comment: what's the size of the progress & track images?

Comment: one is 641X116  and other is 604X108 and progress bar is displayed in 320X60, could size be a problem?

Comment: No. I thought your images are too small. Are you testing this in iOS 5 & above right?

Comment: Yes, I am running it on ios 7 device.

Comment: Try this in code, It's working for me. [progressView setTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"track"]];
    [progressView setProgressImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"progress"]];

Comment: Any idea why is it not working through the property in designer?

Comment: That Might be a bug in xcode :-)

Comment: You might want to move your solution to the answer section.

Comment: Solution added @akshay202 :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this following code in programmatically,

```
[progressView setTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"track"]]; 
[progressView setProgressImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"progress"]];
```

Comment: but setTrackImage is not visible

Answer (score 1):

**A simple solution to override  UIProgressView's tint color :**

```
progressVw.trackTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

**If you want to set backColor of UIProgressView-**

Use this [Custom UIProgessView](https://github.com/PascalW/PDColoredProgressview)

**If you want to set Progress image and Track Image  of UIProgressView-**

Refer this link [Progress image and Track Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980891/uiprogressview-and-custom-track-and-progress-images-ios-5-properties)

Comment: I dont want to use tintcolor at all, I want to use images. How to I tell it to not use tint color and use Progress image and Track image instead.