# UIProgressView: modify height for track line

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, user-interface, progress-bar

Currently I'm able to customize my progress bar modifying the whole height, in this way:

```
let transformScale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, newProgressbarHeight)
self.progressBar.transform = transformScale
```

There is a way to modify the height of track in order to obtain a progress bar like this?

[image]

As a workaround I was pondering of put a gray view under the progress bar track tint color to clear color.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using resizable images for progress and track bar as per your need. here is a ex in which it explained how to use images in these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980891/uiprogressview-and-custom-track-and-progress-images-ios-5-properties

Answer (score 2):

iOS 5 or later, `UIProgressView` could set its `FrontProgress` Image(Green Fat)
And its `Background` Image(Gray Slim).
You could set Two different picture to simulate this effect.
**Front Image property: progressImage.
Background Image property: trackImage.**
Or,
 If you only like Pure Color to avoid wasting any resource, I think the method below will fit your demand.

1.Create two UIProgressView.Fat and Slim, Front and Behind.

**2.Set the Front One's trackTintColor [UIColor clearColor].**

[The code and effect in simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLziZ.png)
I hope these could help you. Good Luck!